# Error : http query string is too long

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, response, httpruntime

I use the below code in mvc to download Excel file but it shows error query string too long.

```
public ActionResult Download(string input)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= download.xlsx");
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/Excel");
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.WriteFile(input);
    Response.End();

    return Content(String.Empty);
}
```

Comment: whats the file name? can you copy it to a temp location with a shorter file path name?

Comment: also you should use the `File()` method instead of writing the response directly. Usage: `Download(string input) { return File("download.xlsx"); }`

Comment: 2 questions...1 - what line produces the error? 2 - how does the Download action get called?  If you're trying to call Download using HttpGet and passing the entire excel file as a parameter that will likely be your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me for PDF:

```
public FileStreamResult DownnloadPDF(int id)
        {Document document = new Document();

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
                pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;

                document.Open();

                formatPDF(document, model);

document.Close();

            stream.Flush(); //Always catches me out
            stream.Position = 0; //Not sure if this is required

            return File(stream, "application/pdf", "title" + ".pdf");
        }
```

I really think that your ActionResult will not work.

Comment: I use the File stream It creates same error query string too long. Response.WriteFile works fine IE11 & firefox but not in chrome

Comment: @GurpreetChhabra if the querystring os too long, I suggest you tu use HTTPOST insteread of the implicit HTTPGET if it is possile for you